# Why is DML not allowed on AdditionalNumber?

Tags: dml

The following test method will not compile or save from my IDE.
It give an error of:  "(OIGForceTest) DML not allowed on AdditionalNumber "

```
static testMethod void testGetDirectoryNumbers() {
    // Perform our data preparation. 
    List<AdditionalNumber> addNums = new List<AdditionalNumber>{}; 
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
        AdditionalNumber a = new AdditionalNumber(Name = 'AdditionalNumber' + i, Phone = '555555' + i); 
        addNums.add(a); 
    } 

    // Insert the AdditionalNumber records
    insert addNums;  //DML not allowed???        
    String directoryNumbers = OIGForce.getDirectoryNumbers();
    System.debug('directoryNumbers: ' + directoryNumbers);
}
```

Has anyone  else seen this error?
Is it truly impossible to insert an AdditionalNumber record in Apex, even for testing?
Any workarounds or thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: You could try creating them via the REST API called Apex that should work, but of course will not work in a test, since callouts are not allowed in tests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a `CallCenter` record and setting `CallCenterId` in the `AdditionalNumber` records you're inserting?

Maybe you need to create a `CallCenter` record and include a list of `AdditionalNumber` records in the `AdditionalNumbers` child relationship?

Comment: I was just experimenting with that, and checked the docs. Apparently, you can only create them through the API, and not through Apex Code. See the following code: `DescribeSObjectResult r = Schema.AdditionalNumber.SObjectType.getDescribe();
System.assert(r.iscreateable());`

Comment: Have to use @isTest(seeAllData=true).